# How does signal aggregation work?

Tags: pcb-design, fpga, integrated-circuit, signal-processing, interface

I just wanna know how signal aggregation works.

For example, there is an IC which can aggregate more than two interfaces(I2C, SPI .etc).

Thanks.

Comment: Where have you seen this written. Please link to a site or document.

Comment: Which IC specifically are you asking about?

Comment: If you can't find one, but you need one, just make one with an FPGA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregations are processed signals.

An **aggregator** reads the raw signals and returns interesting summaries, ranging from **simple analog** sums to **sophisticated digital**  functions.